# QGraphicsPixmapItem not selectable

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I want my `QGraphicsPixmapItem` become selectable (i.e. clickable in more general way) on `QGraphicScene` but it doesn't. I'm actually modifying `Qt`'s [Diagram Scene sample](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/graphicsview-diagramscene.html), where `QGraphicsItem`'s subclass is used and is selectable. I appreciate your help.

cpp code (partial):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QtGui>    
#include "overlayPixmapItem.h"

OverlayPixmapItem::OverlayPixmapItem(DiagramType diagramType, QMenu *contextMenu,
                                                   QPixmap img, QGraphicsItem *parent,
                                                   QGraphicsScene *scene)
    : QGraphicsPixmapItem(img, parent), QObject()
{
    myDiagramType = diagramType;
    myContextMenu = contextMenu;

    this->setAcceptsHoverEvents(true);
    this->setAcceptHoverEvents(true); //
    this->setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton);
    this->setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::RightButton);
    this->acceptDrops();

    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
    this->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges, true);
}
:
```

header (partial):

```
#ifndef OVERLAYPIXMAPITEM_H
#define OVERLAYPIXMAPITEM_H

#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QList>
#include <QObject>

class QPixmap;
class QGraphicsItem;
class QGraphicsScene;
class QTextEdit;
class QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent;
class QMenu;
class QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent;
class QPainter;
class QStyleOptionGraphicsItem;
class QWidget;
class QPolygonF;

class OverlayPixmapItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        enum { Type = UserType + 15 };
        enum DiagramType { Crosshair };

        OverlayPixmapItem(DiagramType diagramType, QMenu *contextMenu,
                                 QPixmap img, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0, QGraphicsScene *scene = 0);

        DiagramType diagramType() const { return myDiagramType; }
        QPolygonF polygon() const { return myPolygon; }
        int type() const { return Type;}

    protected:
        void contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *event);
        QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value);
        void hoverEnterEvent ( QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent * event );
        void hoverLeaveEvent ( QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent * event );

    public: signals:
        void mouseHoveredOnElem(OverlayPixmapItem *i);
        void mouseHoveredOutOfElem(OverlayPixmapItem *i);

    private:
        DiagramType myDiagramType;
        QPolygonF myPolygon;
        QMenu *myContextMenu;
};
#endif // OVERLAYPIXMAPITEM_H
```

Comment: At first sight I'd say you don't set accepted mouse button the right way. try `setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton|Qt::RightButton);`, otherwise your item won't accept left mouse button because of the second call

Comment: @totem Why did you write this as a comment? I guess that this is the correct answer to the question...

Comment: @totem As leemes pointed out, your comment was the answer to my problem. If you re-write it in the answer section I'll choose it. Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in my first comment, you call `setAcceptedMouseButtons()` method twice. While the first call actually set the correct button to be accepted, the second call make this setting lost.

To accept both buttons on this item, you have to combine Qt MouseButtons flags, this way :

```
item->setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton|Qt::RightButton) ;
```